# Book on Random Group Theory

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, soft-question, book-recommendation

I'm looking for a book on random group theory. I haven't had any luck in finding books specifically on this topic.

Comment: I think you need to be more specific about the kind of thing you are looking for.

Comment: If, by random group theory, you mean probabilistic group theory, I don't know of a book, but there is a nice survey paper [here](http://people.math.carleton.ca/~jdixon/Prgrpth.pdf).

Comment: @James Yes, this is perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could see this book:
"Probabilistic Group Theory, Combinatorics, and Computing", Springer.

Here is the link: https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781447148135

Answer (score 1):

If by "random group theory" you mean the theory of "random groups" as introduced by Gromov (which is different from the "probabilistic group theory" of the comments and the other answer) then the following book is a good survey:

Ollivier, Yann. *A January 2005 invitation to random groups*. Vol. 10. Rio de Janeiro: Sociedade brasileira de matemática, 2005.

You can download this book from Ollivier's website [here](http://www.yann-ollivier.org/rech/publs/randomgroups.pdf). A brief update from 2010 can be found [here](http://www.yann-ollivier.org/rech/publs/rgupdates.pdf).